# Why are some users every time it registers a new registrationId GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a programm, with GCM. My app use more 1000 people every day. Some (2-3 users out of 1000) users every time it registers a new registrationId GCM. Why is this happening? 
In http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html written:

> There are also two other scenarios that require special care:
>
> Application update
>
> Backup and restore

I don`t update app every day.

Comment: Google has been known to generate new registration ids for devices from time to time. I don't know the reason but, I designed my app so that it may update the regid of the user in case of a change. I strongly advice you to review your design to handle this possibility.

Comment: Usually a new registration ID is assigned to an app on a device after the app has been uninstalled and installed again or after the app has unregistered from GCM and registered again. You should debug the devices that get multiple registration ID to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Based on code provided by google, your app should automatically check if RegID is stored in shared preferences. If it is, dont do anything, otherwise register.

```
    // Check device for Play Services APK.
if (checkPlayServices()) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    //Collect Registration ID from Shared Preferences
    regid = getRegistrationId(context);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Collected from SP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //if it is not in shared preferences, re-generate
    if (regid.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Re-Generate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        registerInBackground();
    }
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, regid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    txtRegID.setText(regid);

} else {
    Log.i("MAD", "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
}
```

All client code for GCM provided by Google can be found here: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

As far as I understand, there is no need to re-generate the ID since its constantly stored in the shared preferences (of course you can implement different storage) unless you update the app (which you dont). Once RegID is generated, store it somewhere and then check if if still there, if not - register again.  Unless that is what your app is doing currently and you are still getting new RegID then sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"every time it registers" - you only register once and once again each time after the application was upgraded (stated by Google - for reasons I don't really understand).

You are not supposed to continuously re-register once you are registered.

It is up to Google to return the same registration ID or generate a new registration ID. There are no guarantees given for this (invalid) case.

"I don`t update app every day."

Then your registration logic in your app is flawed.